# ImageMagick generates corrupted PDF file

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

When I try to convert an image to PDF using ImageMagick by executing the command

```
mogrify -format pdf ImageMagick.png
```

the resulting PDF is corrupted. When I try to open it using MuPDF it fails:

```
error: cannot recognize version marker
warning: trying to repair broken xref
warning: repairing PDF document
error: name too long
warning: skipping ahead to next token
error: invalid key in dict
error: invalid key in dict
error: name too long
warning: skipping ahead to next token
error: no objects found
mupdf: error: cannot open document
```

The output of ImageMagick using the `-verbose`-flag is:

```
ImageMagick.png PNG 600x621 600x621+0+0 8-bit sRGB 123261B 0.020u 0:00.009
ImageMagick.png=>ImageMagick.pdf PNG 600x621 600x621+0+0 8-bit sRGB 122974B 0.070u 0:00.060
```

The problem with the PDF file seems to be, that the first bytes of the file aren't `%PDF-`.

This is my input-file [image: input-file]

And this is [the resulting PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dQBarTv5jdlndnn-Qg2S2U_XwJYxji8d)

My system:

- Arch Linux
- ImageMagick 7.0.8-8 Q16 x86_64 2018-08-01 (installed by executing `pacman -S imagemagick`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that `ghostscript` wasn't installed. ImageMagick doesn't seem to throw an error when ghostscript isn't installed.

To install ghostscript use
`pacman -S ghostscript`

Answer (score 0):

Your command is just rewriting a PNG over itself. I don't know how the `ImageMagick.pdf` file was generated, but it really is just a PNG image with a PDF filename. Try one of the following...

```
convert ImageMagick.png ImageMagick.pdf
```

... or ...

```
mogrify -format PDF -path ./ ImageMagick.png
```

Comment: The problem is still the same. But you are right, it only renames the original PNG. It works using my command and your commands on ubuntu though, so the problem seems to be related to my installation...